# asp.net gridview paging

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view which has 10 rows. I have set `paging = true` and `pageSize = 2`

Now when I try to navigate through the page by the below mentioned link like 1, 2, 3
, I then receive error something like need event `pageIndexChanged`.

I added this event but do not understand what code should I add to this event to navigate to next page by maintain the state in each page ?

Please let me know

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is set the PageIndex for the GridView to the new page, and re-bind the control.

```
protected void gridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
  gridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
  BindGrid(); // this is whatever method you call to bind your data.
}
```

**EDIT:**

You should already have an event-handler for the DataBound event of the GridView:

```
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // lots of code here to do stuff with bound data.
}
```

Instead of having "lots of code", you have this:

```
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   BindGrid();
}
```

Therefore on the PageIndexChanging event, all you're doing is re-binding the data (calling the same logic for the DataBound event).

Make sense?

Comment: GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
this is the code which i write to bind my data grid on some button click. so i should re so it and how, you mean i should agian perform the data base operaion here beacue dt id in Button click event and not accessible out side

Comment: Refactor your code in a way that exposes dt to be accessable from the PageIndexChanging Eventhandler

Comment: How can do that so that i can get the same dt again to bind i am really novice to this please suggest me the structure i should have.
because i have dt in button click.
should i declare a dt out side globally but on post back it will make it emapty data table what should i do?

Comment: should i use viewstate or what alternate u suggest

Comment: i have used viewstate but the problem is that cheked check box column 
on navigation becomes unchecked what to do now how to resolve this