# Storing Linq Query In Session

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am tring to store the results of a Query in a `Session` to pass to `PageIndexChanging` event.

When I run the Query I get the exception `cannot access disposed object`.

when I bind the Grid I am adding the Query to the `Session`

```
pnl_results.Visible = true;
ResultsGridView.DataSource = result;
ResultsGridView.DataBind();

Session["ResultQuery"] = result;
```

Then I am trying to use it in the `PageIndexChanging` event

```
protected void ResultsGridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    var gridResult = Session["ResultQuery"].ToString();
    ResultsGridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    ResultsGridView.DataSource = gridResult;
    ResultsGridView.DataBind();
}
```

How do I set the `Session` so I can use it in the `PageIndexChanging` event

Comment: I'm not sure what the exact best practice is in this case, but the `ToString` certainly is not helping your situation.

Comment: Did you execute the linq query on your server by calling .ToList() or .FirstOrDefault() etc..? but my question is where is your linq query? i don't see it.

Comment: @sixlettervariables nope I dont think his result is a string :)

Comment: I'm voting to close as a duplicate of [asp.net gridview paging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594639/asp-net-gridview-paging) because you should requery rather than store the results in the Session object. You'll likely run into problems if you do not rerun the query.

Comment: The `.ToList()` works but now i have a new error..`The data source does not support server-side data paging.` in my `PageIndexChanging`?

Comment: @sixlettervariables I don't agree with you that this is a duplicate... The TS his problem is mostly the Cannot access disposed object problem apart from wheter its good to store his result in the session.

Comment: @JordyvanEijk: sometimes the solution to the problem seems unrelated at first.

Comment: @StudentRik: Are you using a [LinqDataSource](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6026147/7116)?

Comment: @sixlettervariables no a custom query from a button event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep `result.ToList()` instead of `result`.

When you store the output of a LINQ query, you actually are storing `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQueryable<T>`, which is just a *definition* of the query that should be run. Every time you iterate over the result, the whole query will run, so the underlying data (probably an EntityFramework data context) needs to be available, which probably is not. By calling `ToList()` on the result, you *materialize* the query and cache the result. Now you have a `List<T>` which knows nothing about the original query. It is only the result's data.

Comment: Keep in mind if the OP is looking to update/change those objects they'll have to reattach them to the L2S context.

Comment: I only want to page the results so the user can select a result. Which already works it was just the list was too long.

Answer (score 2):

I think the error is that you are storing the IQueryable in session and not the actual result, try to do a ToList() or simular before storing the result;

Answer (score 0):

`(T)Session["ResultQuery"]` generic like using please.

Sample using;

```
protected void ResultsGridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    // var gridResult = Session["ResultQuery"].ToString();
    var gridResult = (Product)Session["ResultQuery"];
    ResultsGridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    ResultsGridView.DataSource = gridResult;
    ResultsGridView.DataBind();
}
```